# Is saving HTML into MySQL database a good approach for a dynamic content builder?

Tags: html, mysql, database

I have a new project coming up in which I have to create a custom content editor from scratch (I will be using Laravel and Vue JS). Each entry will have a structure defined by `blocks` that have rich-text, content `fields` inside them. This would be an example of a desired layout:

[image: Three rows of content]

My question is: how would I go about creating these `block_types` (title, subtitle, three-column row...) and `fields` inside the database? I would think that saving an HTML `structure` field to the `block_types` database table with a placeholder would do the trick.

**HTML longtext saved to the database, into the STRUCTURE field of a BLOCK TYPE**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">///// CONTENT</div>
    <div class="col-4">///// CONTENT</div>
    <div class="col-4">///// CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

I would then add the content dynamically into the `/// CONTENT` placeholder in order. It *does* seem cumbersome, so I think I might be getting into a tricky place from the start, any suggestions?

PS: This would be the db structure I have up to now:

[image: DB structure]

Comment: You're in for a nightmare with XSS. Take a look at OWASP's XSS filter evasion. We have a rather important website and hardening it for XSS injections has been a nightmare due to HTML on the database. Sadly, inventing your own markup (such as BB code) won't help you either.

Comment: The real culprit here is the <script> tag. The data format (BB code, JSON, whatever) and persistance technology (database, files in an upload area) are irrelevant. You have to filter for the script tag on input and that's way more difficult than it seems. Look at [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving HTML to a database is almost never a good idea. The one time this happens is with CMS's where they provide a rich-text interface where the user can style text with simple tags (bold, lists etc).

The fundamental issue with storing mark-up in a DB is you become wedded to its structure since it's hard-coded in the DB.

So for example, what if you one day decide that one of those stored `div` tags should have a certain class? or a data attribute. You'd have to update every single row, or worse still affect the changes in the DOM via JS, which means the resultant HTML in the view doesn't really match what you stored.

Storing mark-up also means storing more data than you probably need, with all that spacing.

A better approach is to define a system of blocks, with a dedicated blocks table which references via foreign key the parent UI table. So it might be like this:

Table 1: UI (an interface, collection of tags, as per your example)

```
----------------------------
| id | ...other fields ... |
----------------------------
```

Table 2: block

```
---------------------------------
| id | ui_id | parent_id | type |
---------------------------------
```

Table 2 would be recursive in the sense it would store both blocks that represented parent containers and child blocks within them:

- outer blocks (containers) would relate to the UI ID via `ui_id`
- child blocks would relate to a parent block via `parent_id`

As for `type`, this is where you can take this approach and run with it. Perhaps that's a string that denotes what type of block it should be (e.g. 'full-width', 'grid-x3', whatever).

Then of course you render this data in the view via something like PHP or JS, again recursively to make sure you get all nested levels.

So let's run some sample data. We'll work with just one 'type' of block for now, a simple 'div'.

UI table:

```
----------------------------
| id | ...other fields ... |
----------------------------
| 1  | ...                 |
----------------------------
```

Blocks table:

```
---------------------------------
| id | ui_id | parent_id | type |
---------------------------------
| 1  | 1     | null      | div  |
---------------------------------
| 2  | 1     | 1         | div  |
---------------------------------
| 3  | 1     | 2         | div  |
---------------------------------
```

That denotes three levels of nested blocks, i.e., when rendered:

```
---------------------
| ----------------- |
| | ------------- | |
| | |           | | |
| | ------------- | |
| ----------------- |
```

Hope that gives you a starting point.

Comment: I think I get your point, so I would pair my parent element's CSS with whatever data comes from the UI table and render/style the children accordingly. I'll give it a go and come back to upvote and accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, much cleaner approach. Using https://tiptap.scrumpy.io as a Rich-Text editor since it returns either HTML markup or a JSON object, which makes this solution easier to implement. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.